# using copula in r with own data

Tags: r, simulation, user-data

I have created some simulated data outside of R (e.g. a matrix with, say, three columns, each with 10,000 values and each with equal probability). An extract of the data is below

```
    Total1  Total2  Total3
1   448824  7895.13 42233
2   297701  8068.44 37376
3   399065  4823.11 10423
4   425672  7567.62 65052
5   487482  7360.86 74758
6   400459  4344.44 39242
7   504143  7336.72 42842
```

I want to define my own correlation matrix between these three variables that are represented by the data in the columns and produce an aggregate distribution using the copula function in R. Do I need to turn the 10,000 values in each column into a distribution first before I can use it in copula, to create a user-defined distribution as the margin object in the copula package?  The documentation says "A user-defined distribution, for example, fancy, can be used as margin provided that dfancy, pfancy, and qfancy are available." So, how do I create the three user-defined distributions for each of my 10,000 values and how then do I apply a copula (e.g. a Normal one) using my own specified 3x3 correlation matrix, to create the aggregate distribution?

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you just want to fit a copula from some family 
(`copula::fitCopula` should suffice, and you do not need the margins),
or do you also want to sample from the copula (in this case, you still do not need the margins)
or from the joint distribution (in this case, you do)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I want to create the joint distribution and then calculate statistics on that joint distribution, such as percentiles, and possibly also sample from the joint distribution. In creating the joint distribution I want to specify the correlation matrix and try different copulas to see the effect of changing the correlation matrix and the copula on the joint distribution.

Comment: The easiest is probably to separate the copula and the margins:
fit the copula (with `copula::fitCopula`) to some family of copulas (e.g., Gaussian),
fit the margins to some family of distributions (with `MASS::fitdistr`, one dimension at a time);
you can then combine them with `copula::mvdc`.

Comment: Thanks.  Will try that and see how I get on.